# Baby Rudin Theorem 2.34

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

So, here's the theorem

> **Theorem 2.34** Compact subsets of a metric space are closed.
>
> Proof.
>
> Suppose $K\subseteq X$, $K$ compact. Let $p\in K^c$, $q\in K$. Let $V_q,W_q$ be neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$ with radius less than $\frac 1 2 d(p,q)$.
>
> Since $K$ is compact, we have $K\subseteq W_{q_1}\cup \cdots\cup W_{q_n}=W$ for some $q_1,...,q_n\in K$.
>
> If V=$V_{q_1}\cap \cdots V_{q_n}$, $V$ is a neighborhood of p which does not intersect $W$, then $V\subseteq K^c$ so $p$ is an interior point of $K^c$. QED.

I'm not seeing how compactness is relevant here. We only need there to be a finite set of q's such their neighborhoods cover K. But this doesn't mean K is compact: there might be an open cover with no finite subcover.
(Actually, isn't there always a finite cover? Just take an open set that includes the set you want to cover)

Could you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: "Isn't there always a finite cover" is not what compactness is about; compactness means **every** cover has a finite **sub**cover

Comment: exactly, that's my point. I was arguing that the property that every open cover has a finite subcover was not used; he just used one finite cover.

Comment: the idea is that you need compactness of $K$ to ensure there exist finitely many $q$'s such that the $W_q$'s cover $K$. If $K$ wasn't compact, you can't guarantee finiteness of the $q$'s (this finiteness is crucial because $V$ is the finite intersection of open sets, and hence still open). What rudin did was first construct a special open cover $\{W_q\}_{q\in K}$ of $K$, then by compactness of $K$, he is claiming the existence of a finite subcover $\{W_{q_i}\}_{i=1}^n$

Answer (score 7):

Compactness is needed for this line in the proof:

> Since $K$ is compact, we have $K\subseteq W_{q_1}\cup \cdots\cup W_{q_n}=W$ for some $q_1,...,q_n\in K$.

Decomposing this line, what Rudin did was consider the (way too big) collection $\{W_q:q\in K\}$ and then note that this formed a (possibly uncountable) open cover of $K$. But $K$ is compact, thus there must be *some* finite subcollection which he called $\{W_{q_1},\ldots,W_{q_2}\}$ which still covers $K$.

In particular, note that compactness guarantees that *every* cover has a finite subcover. If the "*every*" bit wasn't given, then we would not be able to say that the arbitrarily picked collection $\{W_q:q\in K\}$ has such a finite subcover!